# BeanDefinitionStoreException - class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/EnvironmentEndpoint.class]

Tags: spring-boot

While upgrading my spring boot application from spring version 1.5 to 2.0.8 below is error while running application. Any clue on below error will be appriciated.

```
21-12-13 14:03:17.167  WARN  [main                               ]  c.b.c.t.ToggleDecider                                                       - Toggle feature.move.neg.batch.flow.from.kyc.to.decisioning.enabled is not defined, defaulting to off 
2021-12-13 14:03:17.245  WARN  [main                               ]  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext              - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [cardapplication.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/EnvironmentEndpoint.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist 
2021-12-13 14:03:17.245  INFO  [main                               ]  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener                          - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
2021-12-13 14:03:17.260  ERROR [main                               ]  o.s.b.SpringApplication                                                     - Application run failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [cardapplication.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/EnvironmentEndpoint.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:271)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:91)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at cardapplication.Application.main(Application.java:40)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/EnvironmentEndpoint.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:732)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170)
    ... 13 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd' xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.amron.cla</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway-decisioning</artifactId>
    <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>gateway-decisioning-api</artifactId>
  <name>Cobalt Gateway Decisioning API</name>
  <description>Gateway for integration with third party Decisioning engines</description>
  <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <jaxb2_commons.version>0.5.2</jaxb2_commons.version>
    <org.apache.httpcomponents.version>4.2.1</org.apache.httpcomponents.version>
    <cobalt.type>api</cobalt.type>
    <spring-cloud-contract.version>2.2.7.RELEASE</spring-cloud-contract.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.8.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <jvmArguments>
            -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5142
          </jvmArguments>
          <addResources>false</addResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>dep</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>regular</classifier>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <forkCount>0</forkCount>
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
        <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- tag::xsd[] -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
             
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>instant-id-request-schema-generate</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>instant-id-response-schema-generate</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
           
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
       
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    
     
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>gateway-decisioning-db</artifactId>
      <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>system</scope>       
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amaron.cl</groupId>
      <artifactId>toggle</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.745</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>ST4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.24.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
      <version>2.24.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
      <version>2.24.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-bean-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amaron.cl</groupId>
      <artifactId>axon-commons</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.737</version>
       
    </dependency>
    
     
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- for ws import -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end [for ws import] -->

    <!-- test dependencies -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
     
     
    
     
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>axon-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>axon-distributed-commandbus</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
      <!--<exclusions>-->
        <!--<exclusion>-->
          <!--<groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>-->
          <!--<artifactId>axon-core</artifactId>-->
        <!--</exclusion>-->
      <!--</exclusions>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>ose</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <skipAssembly>false</skipAssembly>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <!--<profile>-->
      <!--<id>selectors</id>-->
      <!--<activation>-->
        <!--<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>-->
      <!--</activation>-->
      <!--<build>-->
        <!--<plugins>-->
          <!--<plugin>-->
            <!--<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--<configuration>-->
              <!--<skipAssembly>false</skipAssembly>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
          <!--</plugin>-->
        <!--</plugins>-->
      <!--</build>-->
    <!--</profile>-->
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Please add your pom.xml file

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess. You are mixing frameworks that pulll in various versions of Spring and Spring Boot and you are adding to it by yourself by adding Spring 4.3 dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please explain little in detail & suggestion to resolve

Comment: I already explained that your dependencies are a mess. Use the maven features to figure out which ones are there and properlyl manage them, but as already stated you are already mixing 5.0 (at least) and 4.3 of Spring by your own wrong doing.